# Not able to use weather json API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api

I want to get weather details from this API but for some strange reason it doesn't seem to work.

It's a mashape API. https://market.mashape.com/fyhao/weather-13

Here's what I've tried,

```
function getWeather() {
  var lat=null;
  var lon=null;
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      lon = position.coords.longitude;
    });
  }
  var url =
    "http://simple-weather.p.mashape.com/weatherdata?lat=" +
     lat +
    "&lng=" +
    lon;
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $(".location").html(
        "<h4>" +
          data.query.results.channel.location.city +
          ", " +
          data.query.results.channel.location.country +
          "</h4>"
      );
      $(".weather").html(
        "<h4>" + data.query.results.channel.item.condition.text + "</h4>"
      );
      $(".temperature").html(
        "<h4>" + data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp + "</h4>"
      );
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert(err);
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "X-Mashape-Authorization",
        "MYKEY"
      );
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".info").addClass("animated pulse");
  getWeather();
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:- I am getting an alert error which says "[object Object]" due to the error function in the ajax. I did not see the error at first because I blocked pop-ups on the page.

Comment: can you please specify what error are you getting ??

Comment: @MannanBahelim I am getting nothing.

Comment: I tried this with HttpRequester it returns http response, you need to insert this in your DOM

Comment: @NitinDhomse could you please elaborate, maybe write an answer

Comment: How r u sure about "getting nothing" , if you are sure you are calling `getWeather()` in correct way, have you put alert and checked it is coming to `success` callback?

Comment: You know that you need to send a `X-Mashape-Key` with the call.

Comment: @SjaakvBrabant he is sending, @Sanjay can you please check `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data.source; ` is working as per docs http://docs.mashape.com/javascript

Comment: Guys please see the edit in the question

Comment: I did not get that error first because block pop-ups setting was on

Comment: You have this response => {"message":"Missing Mashape application key. Go to http:\/\/docs.mashape.com\/api-keys to learn how to get your API application key."} , please provide application key with request, See their API docs

Comment: use `console.log(err)` instead of `alert(err)` and you'll see what the error says

Comment: Made some changes, try this https://plnkr.co/edit/ASObd6RBiouMGyEUeyVh?p=preview it works for me

Comment: I'm having the same now, probably because the key got an limit within X minutes or something. It did work his code showed me the country, city and temperature.

Comment: @SjaakvBrabant might be the most flaky api in the world. Out of 10 calls, 1 returned data the other 9 did not.

Comment: @Jamiec I got my own api key and now it works 10/10 (proof: https://i.gyazo.com/e0a36a2d8dacd284efe3655a82ffed98.png)

Comment: @Jamiec hahahahah so cute, if you know my key please tell me it, cause you cannot even see 50% of the key xx

Comment: @Jamiec key is free so there's no need to hide it

Comment: @SjaakvBrabant thats easy to answer. I actually take the time to help people - you might like to go look at how many thousand questions ive answered. How rude!

Comment: @SjaakvBrabant That was actually rude man!!

Comment: @Jamiec It was just cute how you said that my provided code didn't work. While it did work (with proof), and how you said that I exposed my key TO THE  WORLD!!, while you can only see 40% of the key and the key is completely free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things:

- `getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous. In the way you have it set up, by the time the lat and lon variables get set to the coordinates, the $.ajax request will already have been sent with `null` lat and lon variables
- This API wants https and not http
- The header is `X-Mashape-Key` and not `X-Mashape-Authorization`

Here is an example:

```
function getWeather() {
    var lat = null;
    var lon = null;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        //we are putting everything inside the callback
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lon = position.coords.longitude;

            var url =
                "https://simple-weather.p.mashape.com/weatherdata?lat=" +
                lat +
                "&lng=" +
                lon;
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.error('error ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                },
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(
                        "X-Mashape-Key", "KEY"
                    );
                }
            });

        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {

    getWeather();
});
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment - it makes entire sense. Good answer!